# Update NSManagedObject into Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

So I have a tabbed application. The first tab allows a user to enter information in ~20 fields that describe a NSManagedObject. They are then able to save this into core data, and that works just fine.

The second tab is a TableView of all of the existing submissions. Now when a user clicks on a cell in the TableView, it will open up the first tab and repopulate all of the fields that were originally saved into core data. When the user clicks save again, I want the existing submission in core data to be updated, instead of a new insertion into core data.

I have found a lot of information saying that I should make a fetch request and then update it like that. But that seems redundant to me because I already have the object that was saved passed to the first tab/ViewController.

If you could point me to some code that would help my situation or describe a way you might accomplish this scenario, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If you still have a reference to the object, just set its properties to the updated values when save is hit, and call your managed object context's `save:` method.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I still have access to the context used to fetch the items from core data and populate the table view. When the user is updating information, they are doing that in the first tab. The context used to grab the item is from the second tab. When the user selects one of the cells in the table, I pass over a reference of the item to the first tab. Am I wrong in thinking that I don't have access to the second tab's context?

Comment: Depends on if you're working with threads and multiple contexts. If you aren't you should be able to access the managed object context from the `managedObjectContext` property on `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million! If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'd gladly mark it as right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a reference to the `NSManagedObject` in the first tab, you can update its properties to the new values when the user saves. You can then save the changes to your `NSManagedObject` (let's call it `myObject` for simplicity) by calling `[[myObject managedObjectContext] save:&error]` where `error` is an `NSError *`.